# Sql based on dynamic where condition

Tags: sql

I have a query, in this there are multiple conditions based on parameter

`select a,b,c,d from xyz where 
case p='Closed' then (q-r)=0
case p='Pending' then (q - isnull(r,0) )>0
case P='All' then all records to be display`

It gives Incorrect Syntax near line case

Comment: so whats the problem

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried?

Comment: CASE
  WHEN X=Y THEN "XY"
  WHEN A=B THEN "AB"
END as Case_Colum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I got solution for above problem

```
select a,b,c,d from xyz where 
case p='Closed' then (q-r)=0
case p='Pending' then (q - isnull(r,0) )>0
case P='All' then all records to be display

select a,b,c,d from xyz where 
1 =
CASE 
    WHEN p='Closed' AND (q-r)=0  THEN 1
    WHEN p='Pending' AND (q - isnull(r,0) )>0 THEN 1
    WHEN p='All' THEN 1
    ELSE 0 
END
```

instead of `p='Closed' then (q-r)=0`
use       `p='Closed' AND (q-r)=0  THEN 1`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with multiple logical pairs like below:

```
select a,b,c,d 
from xyz 
where 
(p='Closed' AND (q-r)=0)
OR (p='Pending' AND (q - isnull(r,0) )>0)
OR (P='All')
```

The idea is that one of the cases will be true, and if so, it ensures that its paired clause is as well.

Comment: What’s the 1=1 for

Comment: True, it's not necessary here, was just to replace the "then all records" but it's useless.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly suggest me any other solution to change 'where condition' depending on parameter value,

since in given sql *(Question)*, **'where'** condition is depend on parameter **p** value.
You can see in given syntax, if the parameter value is change, condition also get changed.

In first case if p='Closed'  then 
select ... where q-isnull(r,0)=0

if p='Pending' then

select ... where (q - isnull(r,0) )>0

In first condition it is comparing *'equal to'* condition
& in next example it is *'greater than'* zero value.

like in third condition I want to display *all records*.

Here problem is *'case'* structure is only return a value not expression.